# Ubuntu touch backup

Tags: ubuntu-touch, porting-ubuntu-touch

How can I backup my Ubuntu touch data? I am using a Meizu Pro 5.
Are there some commands that can be used in Ubuntu touch recovery?

Answer (score 1):

You can just backup the `/home/phablet` folder. This is were all your configs and userdata is stored. There's a script to do this here: https://github.com/popey/buds